# How many elements in food?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

A slightly deranged curiosity: if we had a 3D printer able to “print” anything starting from “cartridges” of pure chemical elements, how many of the 118+ possible cartridges (or of the 98ish for non-artificial elements) would we actually need to print most - or all - foodstuff?

(OK, one could have phrased the same question in a more mundane way, I agree.)

Comment: maybe you can help answer the question:  can you find a resource that contains an elemental analysis of "foodstuffs"?

Comment: I am confused: I was under the impression that this was exactly the gist of my question and that, not being a chemist nor an experimental scientist myself, somebody could be able to help here. (Moreover, English is not my first language: isn't “foodstuff” a correct word?)

Comment: It's a correct usage of the word.  I doubt you could get a definitive answer, beyond "you need all of them because all elements are in virtually all naturally-occuring composite substances."  You may want to consult a nutritionist if you want to know what is necessary, though they may point out that elements make molecules, and there are myriad molecules in food.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It was a curiosity arisen while speaking with friends, none of which a chemist or thereabouts. We could just figure out that (is that right) we could probably leave out noble gases and the most radioactive elements. As for the molecules, our approach bypassed the problem by just assuming the fictional 3D printer would cater to it, if we were providing it with the necessary elements. Right, we shall go for a complete, 118-element kit...

Comment: Slightly more seriously, I am quite sure about C, H, O, N, and S, and several more, but I don't even know enough to understand whether in, say, a steak “almost all” elements are present, or just a few. But your remark that “you need all of them because all elements are in virtually all naturally-occuring composite substances” points to the former. Is it a quote?

Comment: It's an interesting question--if you've ever seen Star Trek, they have those "food makers" and they have to get their ingredients from somewhere.  Good luck, maybe someone would have a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, I am not a biochemist, a nutritional expert, or any sort of person who is required to know this for my profession.

That said, as far as I know, to get the vast majority of nutritional food substances, you'll need to be able to produce at least:

- sugars and starches
- lipids
- amino acids
- cellulose
- various other non-polymeric organic molecules of various levels of complexity
- salts
- proteins

These together will give you a reasonable approximation of food which will be most of what you need to stay alive, without necessarily going into the complexity of actually producing a better analogue of dead tissue "under the hood".

Sugars and starches are entirely composed of carbon, hydrogen, and oxygen. The same goes for lipids, cellulose, and the majority of the organic components you'll need. For amino acids, and the other organic bits, you'll need to add nitrogen and sulfur.

You also need phosphorus for DNA, RNA, ADP, and ATP, as well as a whole bunch of other signalling and respiration-based molecules, and bone material.

You need sodium and potassium ions which are needed in living tissue for nerve signalling, and you also need calcium ions to make bones.

Many plant materials seem to contain small amounts of boron, though the biological role of it isn't concrete as far as I know.

As far as I know, the proteins are where the metallic awkwardness comes in. A lot of proteins have a reaction site containing a metal, metal-sulfur, metal-porphyrin, or another metal-organic molecule complex, which can come in various metallic flavours. For example, haemoglobin requires an iron-porphyrin complex, while chlorophyll requires magnesium-porphyrin, and a lot of respiration-based proteins seem to involve iron-sulfur complexes.

I'm fairly confident you could make reasonable analogues of most food with C, H, O, N, S, P, Na, K, Cl, and Ca, with relatively small additional quantities of B, Fe, and Mg. You might suffer after a while from micronutrient deficiencies, though.

(I'll probably find that I've forgotten something important somewhere.)

Comment: Well, [the human body has a bunch more](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-79ZzFmrHJgo/Tj1FYu2XlFI/AAAAAAAAAD4/b4eN6oj4JaQ/s1600/human+elements.gif), like Molybdenum. I assume this has to come from food _some_ time. But you're probably right, the majority of food products can be made without the trace elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is 26 - as suggested from this [periodic table of life](http://www.nmsea.org/Curriculum/Primer/forms_of_energy.htm)

[image]

One can estimate that the raw materials in the human body amount to approximately $3.50 (so you probably can't sell off your little brother for more than a buck and a quarter).